# Pausing an endpoint until the promise returns a fulfilled promise

Tags: javascript, endpoint

I'm trying to speed up an endpoint and I think have an idea on how to do it however I'm not totally sure if it is a possible or worth trying to figure out.

Essentially what I want to do is return a promise and then based on the status code 202 or 200 I will determine if the next request should be made or if it should be delayed with something like Promise.all(). The reason I want to try and do this is because using only setTimeout I can only get around a max of 50 request per second and I'm trying to push that to something closer to 200 request per second.

Current delay function for endpoint:

```
const delayQue = () =>{
    if(count % 25 == 0 && count > 0){
        setTimeout(delayQue,1000)
        assignVals(row)
    }
    else if(row < vals.length){
        setTimeout(delayQue,50)
        assignVals(row)
    }else{
        StepData(stepCol,stepVal,count)
    }
    row++
    count++

}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather, and correct me if I'm wrong, you're wanting to make a web request and wait depending on the status?

You're adding things like `setTimeout` delays in your question but providing no code of what you're doing thus far so it's hard to understand what exactly you're asking here.

If you're asking about delaying a new request because of a 202 response, you could just return `new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2500));` instead and make the web request in the next promise or something. This is all situation dependent.

I'm just gonna write a simple promise chain from memory (it may have to be tweaked to be functional) using [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

```js
fetch('myapi.com/resource')
  .then((response) => {
    if (response.status == 200)
      return Promise.resolve() // Immediately resolve a new promise and send it on.
    else if (response.status == 202)
      new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2500)) // Wait 2.5 seconds then resolve.
  })
  .then(() => {
    // continue on with the next request.
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Yes that is what I'm wondering. I wanted to see if there was a way to get rid of any excess time that is caused by the setTimeout. For example while I may wait 2000 mili secs my request might resolve in only 1000 but I still have to wait the 2000 mili sec. I apologize for not adding any code since I was more curious about if it was even a good practice to approach the problem this way. I'll go ahead and add it now.

Comment: You could always just do an increasing retry functionality, so it waits for half a second, then retries, if it's still not processed wait another second, then 1.5 seconds, etc. You'd have to modify the promise a bit and brak it out, but it is possible.